# java: lambda body is neither value nor void compatible

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       ArrayList<Employee> staff = loadStaffFromFile();
       Collections.sort(staff, ((o1, o2) -> {
            if(o1.getSalary()>o2.getSalary() && o1.getName()>o2.getName()){
                 return 1;
            }else if(o1.getSalary()<o2.getSalary() && o1.getName()<o2.getName()){
                  return -1;
            }
       }));
```

help me fix the error please

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 1):

1. String нельзя сравнивать знаками больше или меньше. Вред ли в переменной name у вас число. Как вы себе это представляете? Например, Вася больше Коли или меньше?
2. У вас не описаны все возможные варианты для компаратора: if ... else if ... ??
   Что будет , если оба условия не сработают? Так делать нельзя.

Должно быть примерно так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Employee> staff = loadStaffFromFile();
    Collections.sort(staff, (o1, o2) -> {            
        if (o1.getSalary() > o2.getSalary() && o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()) > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o1.getSalary() < o2.getSalary() && o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        else return 0;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Очевидная ошибка в коде, на которую указывает компилятор,-- отсутствие возвращаемого значения, когда не выполняются оба `if` оператора, и некорректное сравнение предположительно строковых полей `name`.

Однако следует отметить, что сравнивать разные поля/свойства класса `Employee` следует по очереди, а не сразу вместе, так как иначе может возникнуть проблема с нарушением контракта компаратора, т.е. может быть легко нарушена транзитивность: если `a < b && b < c`, не выполнится `a < c`.

Поэтому данный компаратор следует переписать, что удобно делать организовав цепочку компараторов при помощи статических методов `Comparator::comparing`, `Comparator::thenComparing`, `Comparator::reversed`:

```java
Comparator<Employee> sortBySalaryDescAndName = Comparator.
    <Employee>comparing(Employee::getSalary).reversed()
    .thenComparing(Employee::getName);

Comparator<Employee> sortBySalaryAndName = Comparator.
    <Employee>comparing(Employee::getSalary)
    .thenComparing(Employee::getName);

Collections.sort(staff, sortBySalaryDescAndName);
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в лямбде не все ветки что либо возвращают, нужно добавить еще один `else` например так:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       ArrayList<Employee> staff = loadStaffFromFile();
       Collections.sort(staff, ((o1, o2) -> {
            if(o1.getSalary()>o2.getSalary() && o1.getName()>o2.getName()){
                 return 1;
            }else if(o1.getSalary()<o2.getSalary() && o1.getName()<o2.getName()){
                  return -1;
            } else return 0;
       }));
```

Можно переписать код таким образом:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       ArrayList<Employee> staff = loadStaffFromFile();
       Collections.sort(staff, ((o1, o2) -> {
            if(o1.getSalary()>o2.getSalary() && o1.getName()>o2.getName()){
                 return 1;
            } else return -1;
       }));
```

Также странно что вы сравниваете `getName()` если это строка, то нужно сравнивать длины строк `getName().length()` так как строки не подлежат сравнению через операторы `<,>`.